# Building a Roo-Project under Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-roo

I'm doing some experiments with Roo. Now I want to build my project with jenkins. As the aj-Files are generated not coded I dont checkin them to SVN. As mentioned Jenkins builds with a lot of compilation errors.

How can I my build-job teach to create aj-Files? Is it something Jenkins has to learn, or is it something maven has to learn?

Comment: From the little experience I've had with Roo, I suspect it would be easier just to check in `.aj` files.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466152/spring-roo-project-what-should-be-kept-in-version-control

Answer (score 0):

On the projects I've worked on, I've always checked in the aj files, for the same reasons given in Jim's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466152/spring-roo-project-what-should-be-kept-in-version-control)