# Unittesting dependant tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I've searched the site and some literature and couldn't get to a clear answer. I'm trying to learn unittesting while constructing a new webpage that simply works as a whiteboard to which you can add post-its.

I have a Canvas object which represents the whiteboard, and a ticket object to represent the post-its. I have (for now) global function to retrieve the one and only canvas, which i test like this:

```
this.testRetrieveCanvas = function()
{
    var canvas = getCanvas();

    this.assertTrue( canvas != null );
}

this.testCanvasType = function()
{
    var canvas = getCanvas();

    this.assertTrue( canvas instanceof Canvas );    
}

this.testIfCanvasIsReused = function()
{
    var canvas = getCanvas();

    this.assertEquals( canvas, getCanvas() );       
}
```

So, i test for three things:

1. Does the method return a canvas?
2. Is it an acutal canvas?
3. Does the method give me the same canvas always?

No problems so far. But a little later, i'm testing "adding the ticket to the canvas":

```
    this.testAddTicketToCanvas = function()
{
    var ticket = factory.createTicket("yellow");
    var canvas = getCanvas();

    canvas.addTicket( ticket );     

    this.assertTrue( canvas.contains( ticket ) );   
};
```

As you can see, i'm using the getCanvas() function inside my test. Is this a dependent test now? I mean, the first three tests have to pass, if i want this test to be able to run without doubts. If it is dependent, how would i fix this?

Comment: Without the rest of the code I can't help much, but you should take a look at http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/ (chai), http://sinonjs.org/ (sinon) or http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/ (mocha) for an introduction to mocking in javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure what extra code you would need to answer my question. Maybe i'll rephrase: Am i violating unit test rules here, by making the fourth of my unit tests, depend on the first three?

Comment: @DavidMaes More information is needed. What test framework are you using? i.e. Have you written the "assertTrue" method (if so can you include the source?) or are you using this from a library? Also can you also please include the code for "getCanvas()", as this is also needed to answer your question.

Comment: I disagree, i've given all the information you need. The framework is irrelevant as i'm asking a general unittesting question. I will rephrase once more: "Can you use functionality in unit tests, that you have tested in other unit tests? and is this a dependency?" and "if it is a dependency, why and how do you circumvent these type of situations"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you should override getCanvas() to return a preconstructed (i.e. the original constructor isn't called) partial mock of canvas. With that said, if canvas' constructor is an empty function and the getCanvas method has no business logic involved, you shouldn't have a problem.

I'd be more wary of the last two statements used together. `canvas.addTicket( ticket );` is ok, since it's the function being tested. but then you're asserting that you have added the ticket using a method from the same object. What if this method isn't implemented yet, or returns false, or worse true? What if your addTicket method has secondary effects that could make it add the ticket to the list but change a flag that makes `contains()` throw an exception, or return false, or true? What if contains has certain business logic that makes it return false for the ticket your sending it, but true for the same ticket in production environment (i.e. your test ticket hasn't been properly initialized, is missing a state, has been marked as excluded from the environment's business flow), what if it has no logic now, but two months into the project the logic changes so that your test fails but all else works (a new state is added, and objects without this state are deemed non existant, except for clients a, b and c). I could go on.

My point is without the code we can't specifically answer your question, only give you pointers and general answers like the one above. If you really don't want to post code, then take into consideration all of these scenarios, and all the other scenarios you can think of, and if under these scenarios testing your code this way won't break code nor tests now and for the foreseeable future, then you're ok.

Comment: I could indeed make a new Canvas instead of using the getCanvas method. As you noticed, i was looking for a general answer. I'm perfectly wiling to give more code, but it defeats the purpose :). 

For the addTicket / contains methods, i've read many articles about this problem. I cannot test the addTicket method, as the list that keeps all my tickets is private. I have a few options here i think:

- i make the tickets public (which for me is not a good design decision because the canvas has to be able to track all the tickets. 
- i test it as a combination. 

Thanks for the long response

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is, no. 
If your code does not violate any unit testing 
principles as long as you adhere to these [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257560/when-is-a-test-not-a-unit-test).

Usually, with those questions there is a huge discussion about mocking certain parts of your tests e.g. your getCanvas() function. I agree that there is reason behind this discussion and that if you want to proceed with testing or TDD in general you should dive deeper into this topic. (Please refer to this excellent [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) from Martin Fowler).

However, for the question if this is a valid unit test, I think it is not relevant as long as you adhere to the unit test rules.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am indeed eager to dive deeper into this subject. However, there are a few parts of it, that i don't fully understand. 

1) what to test/what not to test 
2) asynchronous functionality (like a method that loads a file and dispatches two events (success and fail) 

I'll dive into the Martin Fowler article shortly. thanks. I wish i could mark you both as good answer.