# Web Resources for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I'd like to start using unit testing as part of my development projects. Can anyone recommend any web resources to help explain how to write effective unit tests? A walk through example project would be useful.

I am predominantly working wit C# and would prefer examples which demonstrate using .Net unit testing tools but don't mind if there is a useful example in some other language.

Comment: Try looking at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/c-unit-testing-example

Comment: See also [What Makes a Good Unit Test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400/what-makes-a-good-unit-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best one I know http://xunitpatterns.com/

Comment: not actually an answer to your question but..there's also this great guide by Misko Hevery on how to write/refactor code to make it more testable (focused on unit testing) http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the Visual Studio Embedded Test. But in the near past I was really happy with NUnit. If you need some mocking, i would suggest MoQ for his simplicity.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Good unit test should make…

- Easy to write tests
- Easy to organize your tests
- Easy to run tests (all, some, one)

I also firstly had experience with NUnit and later moved to MSTest. In my opinion MSTest has 2 strength: it is much easy to create unit test for particular method and run test. The only problem with organising tests in group - that is what was easy to do with NUnit.

More information regarding creating effective unit test for .Net also described [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/presentations/effective-unit-testing.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I very recomment the [Art of Unit Testing book](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) from Roy Osherove. This book is an essense of expirience and best practices. And yes, this is not an web-resource, but you should look to [Roy's blog](http://www.osherove.com/blog/) too.