# How to get Test case Description / Name of test case using testNG when testcases are executing in for loop

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

I am executing test cases based on few constants such as if ADD come then only perform Add functionality and so on... and test cases are executing. I would like to retrieve test case name/ description.
Below is my pseudo code for the test case

```
@Test
public void executeTestStep(String name) {
    if (A.get() == ADD) {
        performAdd(name);
    } else  (A.get() == EDIT) {
        perform(name);
    }          }
```

name is a variable which I am getting from a property file. so I would like to have test case names are 
1. "Add" + name 
2. "Edit" +name
3."delete" +name
Can some one please advise me on this?

Comment: You should probably have individual test cases for each functionality, instead of deciding which one to call based on some test parameter.

Comment: I agree with you, Morfic. but that is how our leadership decided.

Comment: Well if they didn't give you a good reason, perhaps you can bring it up to discussion again, and provide your arguments why having individual tests for separate functionalities is beneficial, eg: improved readability, understanding, maintenance, debugging, easier to find the point of failure, etc (more on quality of a good unit test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400/what-makes-a-good-unit-test))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass by string value,

```
String testCase="";

@Test
public void executeTestStep(String name) {
    if (A.get() == ADD) {
        performAdd(name);
        testCase = "Add Operation";
    } else  (A.get() == EDIT) {
        perform(name);
         testCase = "Edit Operation";
    }  
System.out.println("Test Case: " +testCase);        
}
```

I didn't find For loop in your code, But if it is there we can use it similarly.

Comment: @Eric Please up vote and accept this answer, if you think it has helped you to solve problem.